# Measuing car rotation with Android phone

Tags: android, sensors

I have found many threads about how to handle the device' rotation,orientation with motion and position sensors.
I would like to create an app which i will use  in my car, first i would like to measure the rotation degree of the car. 
So i put my phone to a phone case and for example when i turn left with the car i would like to see the car' turning degree on the phone.

Is it possible by magnetic and accelero meter?

I post a code that for first i think okay. (let's say that i hold my phone "portait" mode so not landscape for first)

```
private static SensorManager sensorService;

//magnetic
private Sensor mSensor;

//accelerometer
private Sensor gSensor;

private float[] mValuesMagnet      = new float[3];
private float[] mValuesAccel       = new float[3];
private float[] mValuesOrientation = new float[3];

private float[] mRotationMatrix    = new float[9];



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
sensorService = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
this.mSensor = sensorService.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
this.gSensor = sensorService.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

sensorService.registerListener(this, gSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
sensorService.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
switch (event.sensor.getType()) {           
case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER: 
System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mValuesAccel, 0, 3); 
break; 

case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD: 
System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mValuesMagnet, 0, 3); 
break; 
}

SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null, mValuesAccel, mValuesMagnet);
SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mValuesOrientation); 

//        double azimuth = Math.toDegrees(mValuesOrientation[0]);    //azimuth,     rotation around the Z axis.
//        double pitch   = Math.toDegrees(mValuesOrientation[1]);    // pitch, rotation around the X axis.
double roll    = Math.toDegrees(mValuesOrientation[2]);    //roll, rotation around the Y axis.

//normalize
//        azimuth = azimuth>0?azimuth:azimuth+360;
roll = roll>0?roll:roll+360;


String txt = "roll= "+Math.round(roll);
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.szog)).setText(txt);
}
```

Questions:
- How accurate will this app in a car? (what can i do to be more accurate?)
- What should i do when i hold my phone at "landscape" mode?
Is the roll from orientation still okay?

Please note that this is a very first try so there are so much to do!
But first i want to see how can i achive that

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had your Android device set up like a compass, then there would be an arrow that always pointed to magnetic north.  So by measuring the change in the direction of that arrow, you could measure the rotation of your car.

To get a better indication of the orientation of your Android device, use 
Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY and Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD, instead of Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD.  This is better because Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY tries to filter out the effects due to the movement of the device.

If the Android device is lying flat on a surface, then the direction of magnetic north is defined by the azimuth that comes out of `SensorManager.getOrientation(...)`.  When it's standing up or when it's on its side then it's a bit more complicated.  However, I suggest starting with the device lying flat first because that's the easiest case, and then you can progress to more difficult cases.

Comment: So looks like the gravity/magnetic field is a better combo, i'll give it a try. Is this combo can be used for very slow speed measuring too? (3-5km/h)

Comment: I don't think it's got anything to do with measuring speed

Comment: Thanks, i think that for my question your answer is OK (now my app is much better!). If you have time please advice me, what sensors are good for slow speed measure? Thanks!